# How to render .hbs using data based on languages.json?

Tags: json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm a starter of the node.js, when i write some .hbs views files, i see someothers like to render the variables like {{name}}.But i don't know how to render the variables which are stored in other json files into hbs template.

I have some language .json files

```
{
"name"              : "English",
"layout"            : "Layout",
"centered"          : "Centered",
"streched"          : "Streched",
"theme"             : "Theme",
"language"          : "Language",
"login"             : "Login",
"logout"            : "Logout",
"username"          : "Username",
}
```

how to render the variables into my .hbs template

```
{{#languages}}
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{string.language}} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul id="x-lang" class="dropdown-menu">
                    {{#language}}
                    <li><a href="#{{key}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                    {{/language}}
                </ul>
            </li>
 {{/languages}}
```

Do i need to write some code in app.js?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are actually compiling the template and passing in the data?

Comment: These code are from https://github.com/simov/express-admin, can you find out through it?

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose. I'm not going to go sift through some docs thats your job. Do they need to be separate JSON files? If you wanted to store data elseware it would be better to module.export an object and require it where you are passing the data the the HBS template.

Comment: To get node to give you an object from that file you need to delete the trailing comma from your JSON object and then 

var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./language.json'))

Comment: And do you have a helper called languages ?

Comment: Thanks very much. I have some idea about this.

Comment: Simply my question, how to render .hbs using data based on languages.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send this compiled templates over express API you will need to user

```
res.send(<templateName>,object);
```

If you just want to compile and get hbs -> html use

```
  var template =  handlebars.compile(source);

  var html = template(data);
```

Check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars)